# Possible to see % uploaded when uploading a file using a form?

Tags: firefox, iphone, upload, itunesconnect

I'm attempting to submit my iPhone app to iTunesConnect. The pictures loaded fine, and I picked "submit binary later" because iTunesConnect kept having the connection reset. I'm using Firefox to upload the binary. Is there any way I can see the % or data transferred of a specific file uploading, in real time? It would be great to see that the bits haven't moved in a while and manually reload the page instead of waiting for the connection to reset.
Cheers

Comment: You might try superuser.com

Comment: This question does not apply any more, you have to use Application Loader to upload binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see if bytes are still flowing, you could use tcpdump.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about firefox, but [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) provides a meter of total uploaded data, as well as transfer rate (I think it also has percentage, but it's been a while).

Answer (score 0):

Outside of browser specific utilities or server encoded features the html specifications for form posts do not inherently have that interface or display. You can try monitoring your local network traffic and disk activity on the device you are sending from, but these come with their own overhead and maintenance. Most of the time when you see progress bars it's because the developer of the application added one.